# Get the value of custom Datepicker and save it to firebase database

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, datepicker

My problem is I want to insert datepicker's value to firebase but Idk how to do it.

I already made an custom date picker but the use of it is to make an placeholder "birth date"
This is my xaml;

```
<frame //some property here>
<stacklayout  //some property here>
<frame  //some property here>
<image  //some property here/>
<grid>
<local:BirthdayDatePickerControl x:Name="entryField_DateOfBirth" >
                                    
                                </local:BirthdayDatePickerControl >
</grid>
</frame>
</stacklayout>
</frame>
```

This is my code(Myproj):
Datepickerctrl.cs

```
public class DatePickerCtrl:DatePicker
{
public static readonly BindableProperty EnterTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: "Placeholder", returnType: typeof(string), declaringType: typeof(DatePickerCtrl), defaultValue: default(string));
public string Placeholder { get; set; }
}
```

this file or code also is save to (Myproj)
BirthdayDatePickerControl.cs:

```
public class BirthdayDatePickerControl : DatePicker
     {
           
            
             public static readonly BindableProperty EnterTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: "Placeholder", returnType: typeof(string), declaringType: typeof(BirthdayDatePickerControl), defaultValue: default(string));
             public string Placeholder { get; set; }
            
     }
```

This is my code(Myproj.android):

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(BirthdayDatePickerControl), typeof(BirthdayDatePickerRenderer))] // this line is outside of my namespace in BirthdayDatePickerRenderer.cs
```

BirthdayDatePickerRenderer.cs

```
public class BirthdayDatePickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
     {
         public BirthdayDatePickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
         {
    
         }
    
         protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker> e)
         {
             base.OnElementChanged(e);
             if (Control != null)
             {
                 Control.Text = "Birth Date";
             }
         }
     }
```

My expected output is still I can place an placeholder to my datepicker UI, and also get that data  from datepicker and same it to firebase.

I tried some trial and error
This is what I've done

```
async public void signButton_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

/*

some code here like assigning firstname or lastname and etc.
*/
  string dateOfBirth = entryField_DateOfBirth.ToString();

   CUSTOMER customer = new CUSTOMER();

   customer.CusBirthOfDate = dateOfBirth;
    var Savedata = await customerRepo.Save(customer);

         }
```

Comment: `entryField_DateOfBirth` is a **control** - if you call `ToString()` on it you will get the name of the control by default.  A `DaterPicker` control has a `Date` property that represents the value the user selected in the control

Comment: it would be a good idea to learn how to use the base `DatePicker` control first, then focus on how to use it in a custom control

Comment: so I will delete my custom date picker sir and I will use the default or base datepicker? the <datepicker> </datepicker>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have done most of the work. Just make a small change to the Button Clicked handler:

```
async public void signButton_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ... 
  
    var date = entryField_DateOfBirth.Date.ToString().Split(" ")[0]; //get the date
    
    ...
}
```

If you want to set the default placeholder of Datepicker to "Birth Date", you should still use a custom render, otherwise xamarin forms Datepicker cannot recognize this kind of string. For more info, you could refer to [Xamarin.Forms DatePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/datepicker).

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for that one sir Liqun. I tried that .Date, it includes the time, is there any way to remove the time? Just only the birthday of the user.

Comment: I have updated my answer to get the date. Please have a try.

Comment: ok sir, I will try to code it now sir, I will update here if what's the result. Thank you master.

Comment: thank you sir, it works. Gobless you sir.